# adding uiimageview inside cell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

trying to load an image inside a cell.
i am able to load the image inside the cell but when scrolling up and down the tableView the image appears randomly inside other different cells as well...

here is some code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


}

if (indexPath.section == ONE_SECTION) {

    switch(indexPath.row) {

        case 0:{
            //some code
}
                break;
            case 2:{
                              //some code

}
                break;
            case 3:{


            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(256,0,43,43)];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
            //imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];}
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

if (indexPath.section == TWO_SECTION) {
    //some code
}

if (indexPath.section == THREE_SECTION) {
    //some code
}


return cell;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code. If you are reusing cells, you dont have to add `imageView` repeatedly to all cells. You can create it in cell allocation part and just set `imageView.image` property out side it as shown below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(256,0,43,43)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    //imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageView.tag = 567; //unique tag
}

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:567];
imageView.image = nil;

if (indexPath.section == ONE_SECTION) {

    switch(indexPath.row) {

        case 0:{
            //some code
        }
        break;
        case 2:{
                              //some code
        }
        break;
        case 3:{

            UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:567];
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == TWO_SECTION) {
    //some code
}

if (indexPath.section == THREE_SECTION) {
    //some code
}

 return cell;
}
```

A better approach is to create custom `UITableViewCell` class and add `UIImageView` inside the `init` method of that cell. Then set the property as `cell.imageView.image = ...` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I get a warning int he line "UIIMageView *imageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:567] for incompatible pointer types initialization *_strong with an expression of type UIView... (im using ARC.... (and when i run the project it doesnt actually do anything different from my code above... I still get the same image in the other cells. I only want one cell to have it and it appears in every cell... Thanks for your answer...

Comment: @GeorgeAsda, Updated my answer. Check now. You need to set image = nil for other cells. And the type casting to UIImageView was missing. I have added that as well.

Comment: @Umka, Yes that is correct. I am not sure why the OP wanted another ImageView. Since the question was about added imageview appearing randomly on the cell, this is the answer. Assuming that he wanted to add multiple imageviews, this was one way to do it. Your point is valid when only one imageview is needed which is not mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using cached cells, the one that you are given may be one you added an image view to on a previous call to your code.  If you assign a unique `tag` to your image view then, for cases where you don't want it, you can check for its presence and remove it if it's found.